# Java applet: connect to "maps.googleapis.com" - access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission")

Tags: java, applet

I'm running a java applet embedded into a Grails application on my local. The applet should connect to the Google Maps API, but it gives me access denied.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-11" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "maps.googleapis.com:80" "connect,resolve")
```

When running the .java file in the applet viewer, the connection is fine, however when the applet is running on the tomcat server, I get access denied.

I've tried every solution I could find - granting permissions, signing the  .jar file, creating and crossdomain.xml file and so on. Nothing works.

I'm running java version "1.8.0_40" on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the your applet inside of a jar and sign it using `jarsigner`

Comment: I did that, nothing changed.

Comment: I created a key pair using keytool, then a certificate and signed the JAR file that contains the applet. Now I get a **Security Exception, found unsigned entry in resource**, warning me that one of the libraries I'm using with the applet is unsigned. I signed this library's JAR file as well, but the error persists.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the unsigned entry error, by resigning every package JAR file, but now I run again into the access denied. It just won't connect to the Google Maps API.